# How to add spring tag <sec:authorize> into Ext JS script?

Tags: html, spring, extjs, spring-security

I'm trying to add a spring balise `<sec:authorize>` on my script Ext JS.
I made the following code:

```
text: 'Management',
    menuAlign: 'tr-br',
    menu:{
        items:[
            <sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADD_SITE')">
            {
                text: 'Sites',
                handler : function() {
                    window.location = "/application";
                }
            },
            </sec:authorize>
```

I want to add tags like above.
Does anyone have any idea to make this?

Comment: what is your error/problem exactly?

Comment: As long as this is a JSP that we're talking about, the code you provided should actually work...

Comment: I don't think so Spring Security has any support for ExtJS at least upto Ext JS 4.2.x and spring 3.2.x, there is no way to do that using standard implementation,  you will need to define your own extentions in extjs and use them as widgets to do that. and your severside api integration should be in place as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can do that kind of tagging, however you can determine user access via a method and dynamically add items in initComponent, e.g.

```
initComponent: function() {
    var me = this
    var items = [];

    if (userInRole('ROLE_ADD_SITE')) {
        items.push({
              // some config 
        });       
    }

    Ext.apply(me, {
        items: items
    });

    me.callParent(arguments);      

}
```

You can see an example [here](http://midrig.com/baff/docs/webapp/source/ImageField.html#Baff-app-view-ImageField).